# Axios.get not returning any data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, http-headers

I cannot get the right info on my API.
I tried this and nothing comes back:

```
const App = () => {
  const res = () => {
    axios.get('https://api.scripture.api.bible/v1/bibles', {
      headers: {
        'api-key': '5b5d4503884b7a2515e8cee8f4b00746',
      },
      
    })
  }
```

Comment: `get` returns a promise, so you need either add `.then` and process the response there, or use `await` (with your function made `async`)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, but you are not doing anything with the response. `axios.get()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you need to handle it using `.then()`

```js
const res = () => {
   axios.get("https://api.scripture.api.bible/v1/bibles", {
      headers: {
         "api-key": "5b5d4503884b7a2515e8cee8f4b00746"
      }
   })
   .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
   });
};

res();
```

or make an `async` function and use [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

```js
const res = async () => {
   try {
      const response = await axios.get("https://api.scripture.api.bible/v1/bibles", {
         headers: {
            "api-key": "5b5d4503884b7a2515e8cee8f4b00746"
         }
      });
      console.log(response);
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
   }
};

res();
```

Instead of `console.log`ging you can do anything, for example use a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function):

```js
const res = async (callback, errorCallback) => {
   try {
      const response = await axios.get("https://api.scripture.api.bible/v1/bibles", {
         headers: {
            "api-key": "5b5d4503884b7a2515e8cee8f4b00746"
         }
      });
      callback(response);
   } catch (error) {
      errorCallback(error);
   }
};

const onSuccess = result => {
   const data = JSON.stringify(result);
   alert(data)
};

const onError = error => {
   alert(`Ops! An error occured: ${error}`);
};

res(onSuccess, onError);
```